# Is it possible that $\|(x_A,x_B)-(y_A,y_B)\|^{\alpha +\beta }\geq \|x_A-y_A\|^\alpha \|x_B-y_B\|^\beta $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha ,\beta >0$ and $x_A,x_B,y_A,y_B\in \mathbb R^n$. How can I prove that $$\|(x_A,x_B)-(y_A,y_B)\|^{\alpha +\beta }\geq C_{\alpha ,\beta }\|x_A-y_A\|^\alpha \|x_B-y_B\|^\beta $$
for a certain constant $C_{\alpha ,\beta }$. I was thinking about Holder, since $\frac{1}{\frac{\alpha +\beta }{\alpha }}+\frac{1}{\frac{\alpha +\beta  }{\beta }}=1$ but it wasn't conclusive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\|x_A - y_A\| \le \|(x_A,x_B) - (y_A,y_B)\|$ and $\|x_B - y_B\| \le \|(x_A,x_B) - (y_A,y_B)\|$.

Raise each inequality to the appropriate power then multiply.

Comment: I denote $x=|x_A-y_A|, y=|x_B-y_B|$ and $z=|(x_A-y_A, x_B-y_B)|$. The only thing I get is $xy\leq z^2$ and thus $x^{\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}y^{\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}\leq z^{\alpha +\beta }$, but I cant get $x^\alpha y^\beta \leq z^{\alpha +\beta }$...

Comment: Do you see that $x \le z$ and $y \le z$?

Comment: Yes of course ! And thus $xy\leq z^2$, and thus, $x^{\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}y^{\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}\leq z^{\alpha +\beta }$, but I don't get $x^\alpha y^\beta \leq z^{\alpha +\beta }$ (or I don't see how). Sorry if my question is idiot, but I really don't see.

Comment: Do you see that $x^\alpha \le z^\alpha$ and $y^\beta \le z^\beta$?

Comment: I'm really idiot ! Ok, it's clear now. Thank you very much,